# Protractor expect direct to a page with specific url

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I have a button on my page, I want to write an e2e test using Protractor. What I want to implement is that when clicking the button, page change to http://localhost:8100/#/booking. How can I implement that?

```
describe('booking function', function() {
  it('should go to booking page', function() {
    broswer.get(localHostCruises);
    element(by.css('.button.button-stable.button-block')).click();
    //sudo code
    expect(page change to "http://localhost:8100/#/book" );
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the `browser.getCurrentUrl()` method, so something like this:

```
element(by.css('.button.button-stable.button-block')).click().then(function () {
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual("http://localhost:8100/#/book");
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with below code.

```
   let targetLocation = 'your/target/location';

    browser.get('localHostCruises'); // Login page.
    element(by.css('.button.button-stable.button-block')).click(); // click on button.
    browser.setLocation(targetLocation);

    // If Login takes some time, so wait until it's done.
    browser.wait(() => {
        return browser.getCurrentUrl().then((url) => {
            let isMatch = url.match(targetLocation);

            if (isMatch) {
                page = new Page; // I assume you writing test cases in page object.
            } else {
                browser.setLocation(targetLocation);
            }

            return isMatch;
        });
    }, 2000, 'Should throw an error message.');
```